# Regarding to acess the home internet?

Tags: router

I have a question which was asked by my professor during the class but i did not know the answer.
The question is that "if i go to another country so how can we access our home university internet from another country?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access your university's network from anywhere on earth, you can do so through a VPN (Virtual Private Network) for example.